# C++ camera component can't look up or down

Tags: c++, unreal-engine4

I replaced the standard blue print camera with a c++ version so it works with my other functions that have been converted to c++

`m_camera = CreateDefaultSubobject<UCameraComponent>(TEXT("camera"));`

but for some reason even though the m_camera node is connected to everything the blueprint node was I can’t look up or down. is there a way to fix this? I have done nothing to change the mouse input part of the default blueprint
[image]

and the components that were part of the original camera were moved over to the c++ camera[image]

I also can't see the details panel for the camera

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check your values for UseControllerRotation

[image]

To see details for the camera it has to have a metatag EditAnywhere in the .h

```
UPROPERTY(EditAnywhere)
UCameraComponent* m_Camera
```

Comment: is that under the camera component? cause I can't see the details for the camera. I click on the component and the details panel is blank

Comment: It's in the pawn. To see details for the camera it has to have a metatag EditAnywhere in the .h declaration, see edit to my post